# How to Run GoogleTV simulator with API level 14

Tags: google-tv

Googel TV [Link](https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_emulator) specified that

> You should use the following settings for your Google TV AVD:
>
> ```
> AVD target of GoogleTV Addon (Google, Inc.) - API Level 12.
> Screen resolution of 720p or 1080p.
> ```

But later, it also said

> Android SDK Tools revision 14 includes support for the TV and media
>   control buttons

Then how to get an API 14 GoogleTV AVD to? 
since in AVD manager I can only choose "GoogelTV Addon API Level 12" or "Android 4.0 API Level 14", there is no option like "Google TV Addon API Level 14"

Answer (score 1):

Google TV supports API level 13 not 14. There is no way to get API 14 or higher support on the emulator or a Google TV.

Recommendation: Don't use the emulator with Google TV SDK add on you don't need it to develop Google TV applications. It is only intended to help you test dpad navigation. Instead I would recommend that you create a Nexus 7 AVD using the normal Android emulator and set it to horizontal mode - this will emulate the 1280x720p resolution of a TV. Unless you are doing coding that is specific to the Google TV media stack you can treat it more or less like a regular Android device (no phone, no camera, no touch).